# SQL timestamp Postresql

Tags: postgresql

только начал разбираться с скл и вот вопрос как написать запрос который выдаст строки за определённый промежуток времени вот к примеру у меня есть поле с типом timestamp,

```
select * from product as p where p.date between '2018-10-00 00:00:00' and '2018-11-30 00:00:00';

select * from product as p where p.date >= '2018-10-00 00:00:00' and pdate <='2018-11-30 00:00:00';
```

ни первый ни второй запрос не помог выдаётся ошибка в обеих случаях 
Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

Comment: покажи вывод `\d product` и `SHOW datestyle;`

Comment: Date style text  ISO, DMY если вас интересует как вбиты даты в таблицу то добавлял я их так insert into product(name, type_id, date, price) values('Домик в деревне', 3, '2018-07-20 00:00:00', 58.00);      т.е. '2018-07-20 00:00:00' вот так у меня внесены данные в поле p.date

Answer (score 5):

Вы не скопировали текст самой ошибки, а только подсказку. Ну впрочем по подсказке довольно однозначно находится [сама ошибка](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/datetime.c#L3784)

> date/time field value out of range

Если внимательно присмотреться к вашим запросам - то нельзя не признать удивление postgresql обоснованным. Даты 2018-10-**00** действительно не существует в календаре.

Comment: вот где ты раньше был я уже сам это вычислил)))